# How to create ldap authorization for asp classic application

Tags: asp-classic, ldap

I have problem with authentication LDAP in aps classic application. I found the script for do it but it is not working. Could anyone tell me what I need to have its done? I attach below the authentification which always returns false. I apreciate for the examples for the variables from this function, becose I dont know where I did wrong.

Thank you for your attention.

```
function AuthenticateUser(Username,Password,Domain)
    dim strUser,strPass,strQuery,oConn,cmd,oRS
    AuthenticateUser = false
    strQuery = "SELECT cn FROM 'LDAP://" & Domain & "' WHERE 
objectClass='*'"
    set oConn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOOBJECT"
    oConn.properties("User ID") = Username
    oConn.properties("Password")=Password
    oConn.properties("Encrypt Password") = true
    oConn.open "DS Query", Username,Password
    set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    set cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery
    on error resume next
    set oRS = cmd.Execute
    if oRS.bof or oRS.eof then
        AuthenticateUser = false
    else
        AuthenticateUser = true
    end if
    set oRS = nothing
    set oConn = nothing
end function
```

Comment: If you delete the line `on error resume next` you might get an error message which could point you in the right direction

Comment: your comment is usefull indeed, dont solve the problem give arguments, thank you!

Comment: I was trying to help. Classic asp gives error messages which point to the line where the problem is.  `On error resume next` tells IIS to continue through the script if it encounters an error.  If you're trying to debug something then it's not something you want to use

Comment: I know, now I can debug so I am thankfull, thank you :)